# Error: call revert exception; VM Exception while processing transaction:

Tags: javascript, solidity

i get this error whenever i try to test my code with hardhat

> Error: call revert exception; VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string "ERC721: invalid token ID" [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-CALL_EXCEPTION ] (method="tokenURI(uint256)", data="0x08c379a0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000184552433732313a20696e76616c696420746f6b656e2049440000000000000000", errorArgs=["ERC721: invalid token ID"], errorName="Error", errorSignature="Error(string)", reason="ERC721: invalid token ID", code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=abi/5.6.4)

here is my  script-test.js code
where could the error be coming from?
and how can i solve it?

```
const { expect } = require("chai");

describe("NFTMarket", function (){
  it("Should create and execute market sale", async function(){
    const Market = await ethers.getContractFactory("NFTMarket")
    const market = await Market.deploy();
    await market.deployed()
    const marketAddress = market.address

    const NFT = await ethers.getContractFactory("NFT")
    const nft = await NFT.deploy(marketAddress)
    await nft.deployed()
    const nftContractAddress = nft.address

    let listingPrice = await market.getListingPrice()
    listingPrice = listingPrice.toString()

    const auctionPrice = ethers.utils.parseUnits('100', 'ether')

    await nft.createToken("https://www.mytokenlocation.com")
    await nft.createToken("https://www.mytokenlocation2.com")

    await market.createMarketItem(nftContractAddress, 1, auctionPrice, { value:listingPrice })
    await market.createMarketItem(nftContractAddress, 2, auctionPrice, { value:listingPrice })
    
    const [_, buyerAddress] = await ethers.getSigners()

    await market.connect(buyerAddress).createMarketSale(nftContractAddress, 1, {value: auctionPrice})

    let items = await market.fetchMarketItems()

    items = await Promise.all(items.map(async i => {
      const tokenUri = await nft.tokenURI(i.tokenId)
      let item = {
        price: i.price.toString(),
        tokenId: i.tokenId.toString(),
        seller: i.seller,
        owner: i.owner,
        tokenUri
      }
      return item
    }))
  
    console.log('items: ', items)
  });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you haven't minted the NFT yet. try minting first

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).